# Ubuntu opencv camera error

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, webcam, camera, opencv

I am using Ubuntu 18 in Virtualbox  and  I am doing objectdetection project in ubunut but I am trying  to open camera using opencv, 
its showing error :VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't find camera device
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

please help  me how to open camera using  opencv in Ubuntu

```
enter code here

import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)

while(True):

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and also I am trying this

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

to change the module it shows another error :

```
FATAL: Module bcm2835-v4l2 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic
```

Comment: Did you set up [Webcam Passthrough](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#webcam-passthrough) from the host to the guest OS?